# How do you change the Excel dataset to read TIME instead of STRING?

Tags: sql, excel

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance

Column 1 in UNION DISTINCT has incompatible types: TIME, STRING at [4:1]

SELECT ride_length
FROM `my-1st-project-230118.my_google_capstone.202204-divvy-trip`
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT ride_length
FROM `my-1st-project-230118.my_google_capstone.202109-divvy-trip`

How do you change the Excel dataset to read TIME instead of STRING?

This error message keeps popping up in Big Query and as a complete novice, I have no idea how to fix it so that I can join the datasets. Quite sure they all have to be the same in order for UNION DISTICT to work.

Comment: Can you add the scema and the query that generating this message please?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cast(ride_length as time)
FROM my-1st-project-230118.my_google_capstone.202204-divvy-trip 
UNION DISTINCT 
SELECT cast(ride_length AS time) 
FROM my-1st-project-230118.my_google_capstone.202109-divvy-trip
```